# Установка OpenWRT на iMx6

Tags: кросс-компиляция, openwrt

Здравствуйте, заказал себе новый i.Mx 6SoloX от freescale. Поинтересовался, возможна ли установка на более старые версии линукс дистрибута OpenWRT. Оказалось возможно, но нужно самому компилировать. Скачал все что надо и делаю по документации, но к сожалению выскакивает следующая ошибка:

```
WARNING: skipping hostapd-common-old -- package not selected
WARNING: skipping eapol-test -- package not selected
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/openwrt/Downloads/Openwrt/gateworks-openwrt/trunk/package/network/services/hostapd'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/openwrt/Downloads/Openwrt/gateworks-openwrt/trunk'
package/Makefile:170: recipe for target '/home/openwrt/Downloads/Openwrt/gateworks-openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9+neon_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/stamp/.package_compile' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/openwrt/Downloads/Openwrt/gateworks-openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9+neon_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/stamp/.package_compile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/openwrt/Downloads/Openwrt/gateworks-openwrt/trunk'
/home/openwrt/Downloads/Openwrt/gateworks-openwrt/trunk/include/toplevel.mk:171: recipe for target 'world' failed
make[1]: *** [world] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/openwrt/Downloads/Openwrt/gateworks-openwrt/trunk'
```

Comment: слишком мало информации. добавьте, пожалуйста, параметр `V=s` к вызову программы `make`, чтобы увидеть подробности сборки.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор предоставил недостаточно информации и на просьбу предоставить не откликается.